# Twilio webhook (NodeJS) - On inbound call, pass call's SID

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm looking to have the webhook which I pass back TwiML whenever there's a call coming inbound pass me the call's SID so in the future I can modify that active in-bound call. For example, (480)-000-000 is calling my Twilio number which then sets off the webhook to retrieve the TwiML. My server will then also get the SID for that call coming in, and send back TwiML to play lobby music. From then my server will have the SID stored into an array for people in the lobby. And one by one connect them with agents as they become open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Good news, every webhook for an incoming voice call to your Twilio number includes the [`CallSid` in the request parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters).

The parameters are sent to your URL as URL encoded form data so if you're using a web framework it should be fairly straightforward to read the `CallSid` from the request.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Perfect, I was having trouble finding information about that. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, happy to help! :)